# Why does CasperJS capture is not working?

Tags: javascript, casperjs

Hope you are doing well,

Purpose: Take Screenshot when page is fully loaded

Tried: Already tried with wait for some MS and when id was found take SS.
But it wan't work as of now...

```js
casper.waitFor(function StepOne() {
    casper.wait(25000, function () {
        casper.echo('after 25 sec');
        casper.capture('screenshots/SS1.png');
    });

    casper.waitForSelector('#Row1',
    function success() {
        casper.CustomEcho('ID FOUND');
        casper.capture('screenshots/SS2.png');
    },
    function fail() {
            console.log("oops! ID is not Found..!.");
        }
    );
    return true;
}, function StepTwo() {
    casper.capture('screenshots/I_Am_in_Then_SS3.png');
    casper.CustomEcho('*****_exit_*********');
    casper.exit();
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can u post what you got printed in console after running the script?

Comment: as shown in code (casper.echo & casper.CustomEcho(UDF))

Comment: do you get `screenshots/I_Am_in_Then_SS3.png` or `ID FOUND`

Comment: Yes, but screenshots after that statement is fully blank (with white bg)!

Comment: Is the url is HTTPS? if so use `--ignore-ssl-erros=true` in cmd line

Comment: @Cut-n-paster Already Tried! no use

Comment: the `return` statement inside first `waitFor` returns immediately without waiting for the `wait` statements.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157436/discussion-between-cut-n-paster-and-unknown-coder).

Answer (score 0):

```js
casper.wait(25000, function() {
  casper.echo('after 25 sec');
  casper.capture('screenshots/SS1.png');
});

casper.waitForSelector('#Row1',
  function success() {
    casper.CustomEcho('ID FOUND');
    casper.capture('screenshots/SS2.png');
  },
  function fail() {
    console.log("oops! ID is not Found..!.");
  }
);

  casper.capture('screenshots/I_Am_in_Then_SS3.png');
  casper.CustomEcho('*****_exit_*********');
  casper.exit();
```

This may work, I 've not tested.

Comment: Sorry bro. what is the use of `casper.waitFor(function StepOne() {
  return true;` here?

Comment: bUT iT wAN'T wORK